# Reading a csv file in Azure Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, azure, csv, path, jupyter

I wanted to read a file in a script and then I realized there is a specific working directory that it reads files from. How can I find that out? Alternatively, if I uploaded my files in the "Data" section on Azure, how should I specify the path to the file put on cloud?

Does Azure read the files from the local machine at all?

I would like someone to help me with using Azure notebooks and reading files in general.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure read the files from the local machine at all?

You can upload them to your storage account or databricks local folders and then read from them.

> how should I specify the path to the file put on cloud?

If you are uploading, it from your local machine then the files are stored by default in `/FileStore/tables/< FILE_NAME >`

[image]

Consider if you are trying to write to a location in your databricks, then you are directly use the below syntax.

```
FilePath = "FileStore1/data"
df.coalesce(1).write.csv(FilePath)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Where is the FileStore located? I cannot find it...

Can you please what writing a location in databricks means and when to use the syntax that you indicated?

Comment: You can find FileStore in DBFS https://i.imgur.com/CaKEaDq.png. Write to a location in your databricks means that when you are trying to upload a file other than the default location you can use the above syntax. By default you cannot create FIleStore directly from the UI, So you can just use the above syntax to create so.